# Bundle IDs and iOS Developer Teams

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have my personal Dev Account and recently was invited via an email (separate email, that I do not user with other iOS Dev accounts) to be a part (join) of one company Developer account. I can access and login via that Developer account and create app IDs, bundle IDs and so on but when I login to iTunes Connect with that same email i can only see one company bundle ID like company* and not the ones that I have created.

Did the person that invited me made a mistake by checking some limitations, is it a bug* or is this limitation by default?

**I had used that same email as a part of iTunes Connect technical role for another app that I no longer develop/support, could this be causing some mixup with accounts and so on?

Comment: Check what your role in iTunes Connect. Click on the People button on the iTunes Connect Home Page.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same infuriating scenario. I'm assuming iTunes Connect is either deficient when it comes to supporting userids related to two teams or I just don't know how to switch my iTunes Connect login to use the correct team. Everywhere else I login I get prompted as to which team I wish to use for the new session.

Apple developer Technical Support came to my rescue:

1. Create a new, free, Apple Developer ID
2. Have my existing iTunes Connect account one add the new id to iTunes Connect as an Admin
3. Have the second, new, account use iTunes Connect to remove the first ID.
4. The first ID can now be added to my preferred team account in iTunes Connect